# Find specific elements with a given order in quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group

[image]

How can I deal with the quotient group generated by several element? And how can I find the element with a given order.

Comment: What is your group operation here? Pointwise addition?

Comment: @enedil Maybe I hadn’t describe it precisely, I mean, I don’t know the structure of the quotient group mentioned in question, and I also wonder how can I find the elements in the quotient group with order 2.

Comment: I mean, if $\mathbb Z^3$ is a group, what operation do you equip it with? So far it has nothing to do with the structure of $G$.

Comment: @enedil Normal vector addition.

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z v_1 + \mathbb Z v_2 + \mathbb Z v_3$?

Comment: @enedil Subgroup of $\mathbb Z^3$ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89504/discussion-between-enedil-and-midas-hu).

Comment: Have you covered Smith normal forms and the stacked bases theorem?